# Fill grouped object into expanded dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following result of a group and sum operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['0','0', '0', '0', '1', '1'],
                   'date':['2018-12', '2019-02', '2019-03', '2019-04', '2019-04', '2019-06'],
                   'val':[2,11,3,7,8,5]})
df.groupby(['id', 'date']).sum()
```

```
            val
id  date    
0   2018-12   2
    2019-02  11
    2019-03   3
    2019-04   7
1   2019-04   8
    2019-06   5
```

I want to expand the second level index for every id to encompass all twelve months of 2019, dropping all non-2019 entries.

I succeeded at creating an empty dataframe like this:

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 30)
columns = ["{}-{:0>2}".format(x.year, x.month) for x in pd.date_range(start, end, freq='M')]

pd.DataFrame(0, index=df.id.unique(), columns = columns)
```

```
    2019-01 2019-02 2019-03   ...   2019-11 2019-12
0         0       0       0   ...         0       0
1         0       0       0   ...         0       0
```

And then using `.iteritems()` on my grouped dataframe, filling the target dataframe element by element.
But this is (in my case) awfully slow and imho rather inelegant. Is there a better way to do this?

And if someone can think of a better title for this question, please update it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For remove non matched values with add non exist columns use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), but before reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) (also add `['val']` after `groupby` for `Series`):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['id', 'date'])['val'].sum()
         .unstack(fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
date  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06
id                                                        
0           0       11        3        7        0        0
1           0        0        0        8        0        5
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='date', values='val', aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
         .reindex(columns, axis=1, fill_value=0))
print (df1)
date  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06
id                                                        
0           0       11        3        7        0        0
1           0        0        0        8        0        5
```